# How do I limit hover to not apply to all the links at once?

Tags: html, css

I am currently building a website but having trouble with the links display when I apply hover (CSS+HTML5). How do I stop the hover to apply on all the links that are on the same line at once? like I want the hover to apply to the pointed link only and not all of them at once. The links are on the navigation bar. Please help me.

Here is what my program looks like:

```css
a:link {
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}

nav:hover {
  background-color: #ff3399;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="/home/">HOME</a>
  <a href="/marchendise/">MARCHENDISE</a>
  <a href="/transportation/">TRANSPORTATION</a>
  <a href="/ciment/">CIMENT</a>
  <a href="/locations/">LOCATIONS</a>
  <a href="/laiterie/">LAITERIE</a>
  <a href="/contacts/">CONTACTS</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: `<nav>
<a href="/home/">HOME</a>
<a href="/marchendise/">MARCHENDISE</a>
<a href="/transportation/">TRANSPORTATION</a> 
<a href="/ciment/">CIMENT</a>
<a href="/locations/">LOCATIONS</a>  
<a href="/laiterie/">LAITERIE</a> 
<a href="/contacts/">CONTACTS</a>
</nav>`

Comment: for styling this is what I had : a:link {
    color: white;
    padding:10px;
       }

nav:hover{
    background-color:#ff3399;
    
}

Comment: please add your code to question

Comment: you are applying hover on nav,not on links, thats why it gets applied on all the links which are under nav tag

Comment: Please add your code so we can help you. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are applying background to the `nav` element on hover i.e `nav:hover`, not to `<a>`.

Just use `a:hover`

```css
a:link {
  color: #000;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #ff3399;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="/home/">HOME</a>
  <a href="/marchendise/">MARCHENDISE</a>
  <a href="/transportation/">TRANSPORTATION</a>
  <a href="/ciment/">CIMENT</a>
  <a href="/locations/">LOCATIONS</a>
  <a href="/laiterie/">LAITERIE</a>
  <a href="/contacts/">CONTACTS</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Bhuwan thank you for your help. This was so much helpful, I still have a long way to go obviously, but I trust that with this community I will improve my web developing skills! 

Comment: @BienfaitKirivita Glad it helped you...and yes this community is the best platform to learn.

Answer (score 0):

you have to be spesific
I recommand you to learn more about selector in css:https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

```css
nav a:hover{
color:red
}
```

```html
<nav> <a href="/home/">HOME</a> 
<a href="/marchendise/">MARCHENDISE</a>
<a href="/transportation/">TRANSPORTATION</a>
<a href="/ciment/">CIMENT</a> 
<a href="/locations/">LOCATIONS</a> 
<a href="/laiterie/">LAITERIE</a>
<a href="/contacts/">CONTACTS</a> 
</nav>
```

Comment: OH wow, thank you so much ! I had been trying to fix this for like days. I am really thankful. Also, I am self-taught when it comes to HMTL+CSS, that's why I sometimes do not understand the codes until I get errors.